# gui for managing virtual machines

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, virt-manager

I want to manage a bunch of KVM VMs on my linux desktop with different types of network connectivity options. Is virt-manager the best option to manage the VMs or are there better alternatives ?

Answer (score 1):

Virtual machine manager is built on top of libvirt. If you are using gnome as a DE, there is a gnome application named gnome-boxes that is also built on top of libvirt and maybe it is worth checking out.

https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Boxes

http://www.howtogeek.com/213922/easily-create-kvm-virtual-machines-on-linux-with-gnome-boxes/